# scala filter by column presence

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have many json string lines in many files and they are very similar in schema but there are a few different in some cases.

I made a DataFrame from them and want to see only rows which have a specific column like

```
DF.filter("myColumn" is present).show
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Thank you @mrsrinivas. It works well! please, add your answer to the answer box so I can make it checked. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `isNotNull` in `filter()`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.isNotNull

df.filter($"myColumn".isNotNull)
```